# Deny access to a location even if auth is provided

Tags: apache-2.2

We have some apache servers that include password protection at various levels.  For example, for test/staging systems we have `/` password protected and requiring specific usernames:

```
<Location />
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "By Invitation Only"
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/passwd
  Require user staging demo test
</Location>
```

In the same setup we also protect other locations:

```
<Location /api/billing>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Billing"
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/billingpasswd
  Require user billing 
</Location>
```

I've now been asked to restrict yet another location based on IP address.  In this case all previous passwords should work as they have, but even if a password is provided we want to deny access to the new location based on IP only.

```
<Location /newlocation>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    Allow From 1.2.3.4/24
</Location>
```

If this new `Location` directive includes `Satisfy  All` then I get a 403 (Forbidden) error even when trying to connect even if I'm connecting from one of the allowed subnets.  If I change it to `Satisfy Any` then I can connect to /newlocation from any IP address whether it's listed as allowed or not.

What's the correct way of restricting access to a new location based on IP no matter what other auth may have succeeded?

These Apache servers are just front-ends for Tomcat apps, so there's no actual directory structure that I can drop a .htaccess file into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually needed to do a combination of things since I already had this defined, as mentioned in the original question:

```
<Location />
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "By Invitation Only"
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/passwd
  Require user staging demo test
</Location>
```

In order to restrict access to `/newlocation` by IP, even when a valid password was supplied, I needed to include the above as well as the IP ranges and specify `Satisfy All`:

```
<Location /newlocation>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "By Invitation Only"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/passwd
    Require user staging demo test
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From 1.2.3.4/24
    Satisfy All
</Location>
```

Comment: Can you set your answer as valid ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Directive `Order` parameters order are important. 
You set `Order Deny,Allow` instead of `Order Allow,Deny`

This is the configuration you are looking for :

```
<Location /newlocation>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow From 1.2.3.4/24
  Satisfy any
</Location>
```

Will allow only IP range 1.2.3.4/24 to display /newlocation path

Comment: Actually, according to the Apache [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order), `... the order in which lines appear in the configuration files is not significant -- all Allow lines are processed as one group, all Deny lines are considered as another, and the default state is considered by itself.`. Unless you mean the keywords used for the `Order` directive, in which case yes, that is important.

Comment: I edited my post to be more accurate, i didn't noticed that could be confusing, thanks